# conflict with scrollview and tableVIew didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a view with 2 children: page control and a scroll view which manages 2 pages of dynamic content which each page showing a UITableViewController. The user should be able to swipe horizontally and see the 2nd scroll view content.

I've been successful in passing dynamic data into the 2 content tables, but I have 3 issues:

1) I can't figure out why I don't see any detail disclosure icons in the prototype cells I've configured for BOTH content tables.

2) In storyboard, I set outlets from each table view cell to PUSH a segue to a new view controller, but that segue never fires?! How is that possible?

3) I NSLog(indexPath) and even if I click on the same row, it ouputs a different index path? Is there some overlap or some sort of conflict between event handling on the Scroll View and the table delegate method -didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Do I need to disable any sort of gestures while selection happens over a table view or something...? Thanks for the help.

**Update: Using Page View Controller instead of Scroll View: same result**

Ok, so I switched to a Page View Controller implementation and the same exact result and I see the same 3 issues reported above. I am going to show the page view controller approach I used as the scroll view implementation was too long.

I have 2 classes: (1) a page view controller and (2)one content view controller.

The concept I am trying to get at is to show a mailbox type scene where I track the users sent messages and received messages (NSArrays). One tableview will show sent messages, the other the "received" messages.

**2 Classes**

CustomMessagePageViewController : UIPageViewController

CustomMessageContentViewController : UIViewController

**CustomMessagePageViewController.m**

```
@implementation CustomMessagePageViewController
{
    NSArray *sentMesages;
    NSArray *receivedMessages;
}

@synthesize pageTitles=_pageTitles;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _pageTitles = @[@"Latest Messages", @"Sent Messages"];

    // initialize page view controller
    self.dataSource = self;
    CustomMessageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((CustomMessageContentViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((CustomMessageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTitles count];
}
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
- (CustomMessageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    CustomMessageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customMessageContentID"];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;
    pageContentViewController.messageArray = (index)?sentMesages:receivedMessages;

    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

**CustomMessageContentViewController.h**

```
@interface CustomMessageContentViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property NSString *titleText;
@property NSArray *messageArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *messageListTableView;

@end
```

Comment: It is possible that having a `UIScrollView` with two `UITableViews` could conflict, but it doesn't sound like that's what your problem is. Could you post some code showing how you're setting up those 3 views?

Comment: @brimizer I updated the post to show the details about how I setup the page view controller. The table view code is uninteresting and is just basic vanillla table view delegate method handling code. Please let me know if you need any other details. Thanks!